# Link a search field to a specific Document Library

Tags: search, search-scope

I am rebuilding our contact centers self help page and am trying to do some fun things with custom search fields on that page. My question is how do I customize the search field so that it only retrieves items from a specific document library or libraries? I only want these search boxes to pull from our list of user FAQs, tutorial videos, and self-help blog entries.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? When you say "Search Field" do you mean the Search Box?

Comment: Well I have made some progress. I am using SharePoint 2010 and have defined a custom search scope with the rules that I want. When I use the sites search function it works and I can select the scope that I want. However I am trying to add a search box web part to my user front end page and make it default to using this new scope without having the scope dropdown displayed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 you can create a Search Scope that only includes your content. It sounds like you got that part. If your only choice is to change the Search Box properties, change the "Additional query terms" property to "s=Scope" where Scope is your scope name.

An easier approach is to create a new Results page and set the Search Core Results web part to use your new scope. Then specify your new results page as the "Target search results page" in your search box.

Comment: Can you guys type out specifics in how you did this? I'm in the process of doing this as well and could use all the help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of steps. I detailed them here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2011/09/09/getting-started-with-search-results/